# Uwp app is getting crashed when system goes in sleep mode

Tags: uwp, crash

When I close the laptop lid or machine goes into sleep mode, my uwp app is crashing sometimes. Error in Event Viewer is

```
Log Name:      ApplicationSource:    
ESENTDate:     26-08-2020 13:01:29
Event ID:      455
Task Category: Logging/Recovery
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SanjayWinTest
Description:svchost (11324,R,98) TILEREPOSITORYS-1-5-18: Error -1023 (0xfffffc01) occurred while opening logfile C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer\Database\EDB.log.Event Xml
```

and one Application Error

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          26-08-2020 12:48:30
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SauravWinTest
Description:
Faulting application name: appname.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 
0x5f368d96
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.18362.997, time 
stamp: 0xb0817f1e
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0086c074
Faulting process id: 0x21a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d67ad6c9f2478c
Faulting application path: C:\Program 
   Files\WindowsApps\appPath\appname.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: bfa922be-6a95-46b9-945e-91f1e53e3758
Faulting package full name: Package name
Faulting package-relative application ID: App Event Xml:
```

Comment: please open the Event Viewer and navigate to Windows Logs -> Application. It will contain all application logs including errors, You could find the app's crash log

Comment: Got this error, but i have no idea why this happened      Description:
svchost (11324,R,98) TILEREPOSITORYS-1-5-18: Error -1023 (0xfffffc01) occurred while opening logfile C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer\Database\EDB.log.

Comment: Ok，I got it, unfortunately, we can't detect the problem with above logs, could you share a sample with github or onedrive that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570356/uwp-app-is-getting-crashed-with-an-error-the-application-crashed-the-parame   @NicoZhu-MSFT can you please check this question

Comment: @Mariusz did you get any solution for this kind of crash?