# Uwp app is getting crashed with an error - “The Application Crashed - The Parameter is Incorrect”

Tags: uwp, crash

I have a chat application which is frequently getting crashed while I scroll to the messages at the top.

```
private async Task ScrollIntoViewWithDelayAsync(int message)
    {
        await DispatcherHelper.ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageList != null && MessageList.Count > 0 )
                {
                    ObjFactory.Instance.CreateLogger().Log("ScrollIntoViewWithDelayAsync Start", GetType().Name, false);

                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    if (message > -1 && message < MessageList.Count)
                    {                           
                        _messageListView?.ScrollIntoView(MessageList[message], ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Leading);
                    }
                    ObjFactory.Instance.CreateLogger().Log("ScrollIntoViewWithDelayAsync End", GetType().Name, false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ObjFactory.Instance.CreateLogger().Log("EX= " + ex.Message, GetType().Name);
            }
        });
    }
```

I am not able to exactly find out the reason behind this. But in most of the cases, it stuck in this code because in logs, it only prints "ScrollIntoViewWithDelayAsync Start"

Comment: Hello, there seems to be no clear error message at the moment. In the best case, you can track breakpoints in debug mode to check whether the method is executed correctly. You can also try to call the code in the method directly on the UI thread (remove `ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync` and call the method on the UI thread)

Comment: _messageListView?.ScrollIntoView(MessageList[message], ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Leading);
At this line application is getting crashed where MessageList.Count = 124 and message =19

Comment: Hello, If you locate the specific problem, you can view the data structure of MessageList[19] to analyze the cause of the problem.

Comment: I am not able to find the specific reason for crash i could just locate that particular line which is causing the crash. There is no issue in Data structure of  MessageList[19]

Comment: Hello, If you are sure where the problem occurred, you can try some other methods to debug. For example, as I said before, call this method directly on the UI thread, or change some test environments (for example, use a specific fake data to test whether `ScrollIntoView` is executed correctly). Since the error type cannot be accurately known, you need to test according to the actual situation of the project.

Comment: Is there any way to handle this crash?

Comment: Hello, to handle the exception, you need to clarify the cause of the problem. Normally, errors that occur on the UI are difficult to catch. The current error message is not clear. If you can provide a sample that can reproduce the problem, it will be more helpful to solve the problem (you can upload the code without private information to Github or OneDrive)